# SQL Server query without subquery

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following SQL

```
set @ID = '323232'

select 
    tt.ItemOrder, tt.DisplayVal,
    ActualDate = (select mfdate from mfseries where Id = @ID)
from 
    tblTime tt
```

Is there  a way to simplify this query to not use a subquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @date datetime

select @date = mfdate from mfseries where Id = @ID

select tt.ItemOrder,tt.DisplayVal,@date As ActualDate
from tblTime tt
```